# trying live-usb 12.04.1 image on an old desktop

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I am trying to load Ubuntu 12.04.1 32-bit desktop image on an old desktop computer. The system shows the initial menu, but after a while, I get an error like the one in the following two screenshots (it takes a few seconds to go from one to the other in the screen):
[image]
[image]

I tried to load it using the different USB ports at the back of the computer, just in case, and I get basically the same error. Find another screenshot from another try:

[image]

Any ideas what might be happening?

NOTES:

- I checked the md5sum of the iso file to be e235b63c02644e219b7bf3668f479c9e *ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso. I did the 'Test' on the laptop where I created the USB drive, and it loads up correctly.
- The desktop computer in question is an old AMD Duron 1800MHz with 512MB RAM. I ran a memtest on the computer, and all went fine.

Comment: Did you check the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the ISO file

Comment: It looks like a kernel panic. Is this the 32-bit version or the 64-bit one?

Comment: System specs please..

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to run a MEMTest; it's on your LiveUSB and you'll need to run it overnight?

I spotted in your screenshot that you have a "bad_area_no_semaphore" error. This usually means you have a hardware defect in your RAM Memory.

See this Ubuntu Guide on Faulty Hardware
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FaultyHardware

or can you try to install with a [Lubuntu Live USB](http://lubuntu.net/) or an [Xubuntu Live USB](http://xubuntu.org/)? They may work better with very old hardware with low memory.

You can always install ubuntu Unity environment after the system is up and running by doing:
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: it's funny because Wired just posted this about Memory Errors: http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2012/08/chip_errors/

Comment: I did a memtest on the computer, and all went fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may come down to trying the 'Alternative CD'.  I had to do it with 12.04 and a Dell Dimension 4600i.

- [Download the text-based installer (alternate CD)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)